# Можно ли сократить запрос в бд для модели user django?

Tags: python, sql, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это запрос, из модели CustomUser, которая дополняется своими полями и наследуется от главного поля User. В шаблоне я использую только user.avatar и user.is_authenticated. Можно ли сократить количество полей, которые запрашиваются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть множество полезных вещей в Django, которые помогут решить вашу проблему:

- Используйте метод select_related() для извлечения связанных объектов
  в одном запросе вместо выполнения нескольких запросов. Это может
  помочь сократить количество выполняемых запросов и повысить
  производительность вашего приложения.
- Используйте метод prefetch_related() для извлечения связанных
  объектов "многие ко многим" и "многие к одному" в одном запросе
  вместо выполнения нескольких запросов. Это может помочь сократить
  количество выполняемых запросов и повысить производительность вашего
  приложения.
- Используйте метод values() для извлечения только тех полей, которые
  вам нужны, вместо извлечения всего объекта. Это может помочь
  уменьшить объем возвращаемых данных и повысить производительность
  вашего приложения.
- Используйте метод defer(), чтобы отложить загрузку определенных полей
  до тех пор, пока к ним не будет получен доступ. Это может помочь
  уменьшить объем загружаемых данных и повысить производительность
  вашего приложения.
- Используйте метод explain() для анализа производительности ваших
  запросов и выявления любых потенциальных проблем с
  производительностью. Это может помочь вам понять, как сервер базы
  данных выполняет ваши запросы, и внести любые необходимые изменения
  для повышения производительности.

Comment: А что если я не передаю в шаблон модель user, а django сам это делает, из-за чего я не знаю как оптимизировать.

Comment: Django запрашивает пользователя, тк пользователь непосредственно входит в каждый request. По идее особо сильно там не оптимизировать, это просто принцип работы такой

Comment: Спасибо за ответ